# When spring looks to test/resources?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, unit-testing, spring-profiles

Working on unit tests in Spring boot application and came across an issue: I put

```
application.properties 
data.sql
```

files under `src/main/resources`

and

```
application-test.properties
data-test.sql
```

files under `src/test/resources`

But realized when @SpringBootTest starting it anyway uses data.sql from  `src/main/resources`
Browsing internet ( and this site particularly) I found the solution:

1. use `@ActiveProfiles("test")` with @SpringBootTest
2. `spring.datasource.platform=test` `in application-test.properties`

But even after that I realized `data.sql` is still working. Actually I see the right way: use profiles for everything: test, dev, etc. And put `profile=dev` in run configuration and rename `data.sql` to `data-dev.sql`

So may be may be it worth to go further and manually define everything: 3.`@TestPropertySourcelocations="classpath:test.properties"`

OR

```
@TestPropertySource(properties = {
                "spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=validate",
                "liquibase.enabled=false"
        }
)
```

OR

```
@Sql({"/data-test.sql"})
```

So my question is: is putting files under `src/test/resources` **gives nothing** in prior of `src/main/resources`? And anyway need to care about profiles ( which seems a silver bullet in this context).
Why spring doesn't understand that it should use resources from `src/test/resources` while testing?

(from my point now it seems completely misleading such secularization to `src/test/resources` and `src/main/resources` which seems looks promising but gives nothing... what I'd like to see: put file at `main` and expect it in main app, put the file with the same name under `test` and expect it uses while uni testing only)

Comment: You have put a profile specific file in `src/test/resources`. When running tests the classpath is the combination of `test` and `main` where `test` is taking precedence. So if there is no `data.sql` in `src/test/resources` it will look in the remainder of the classpath for it. The `data.sql` and `application.properties` are always loaded.

Comment: Does the ----- 1)`src/test/resources` is taking precedence & 2) `data.sql` and `application.properties` are always loaded ------ together mean: regardless what is under `src/test/resources` the `src/main/resources/application.properties` & `src/main/resources/data.sql` will be always picked?

Comment: springboot auto look for file by file name - if the file name is the same in test and main resources folder, it chooses firstly from `main`, secondly from `test` - the file name must be specific for the test